# Matching a time interval using regex

Tags: java, beginner, datetime, regex

What I needed to do was check whether a given string matches a certain pattern. The pattern is this:

```
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
```

Things to keep in mind:

The 0s can be numbers from 0 to 9.

The pattern must be alone in a single line; the line has to only consist of the pattern.

I came up with this:

```
"^(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d),(\\d\\d\\d) --> (\\d\\d):(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d),(\\d\\d\\d)"
```

I tested it a few times and strings that respect the pattern return `true`, the ones that don't, return `false`, as they should.

Here's a test case:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestCaseRegex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //will return true
        String testOne = "00:01:23,846 --> 00:01:26,212";

        //will return false, there's a letter where a number should be
        String testTwo = "00:01:23,84a --> 00:01:21,221"; 

        //will return true
        String testThree = "00:05:54,846 --> 00:01:16,450"; 

        //will return false. The string doesn't match the format.
        String testFour = "00:05:54,6 --> 00:0116,450"; 

        System.out.println(patternMatch(testOne));
        System.out.println(patternMatch(testTwo));
        System.out.println(patternMatch(testThree));
        System.out.println(patternMatch(testFour));
    }

    public static boolean patternMatch(String str) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d),(\\d\\d\\d) "
                + "--> (\\d\\d):(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d),(\\d\\d\\d)");
        return p.matcher(str).matches();
    }

}
```

As I'm very new to regex, I'm wondering if this is the most efficient/correct way to accomplish this.

Comment: Suppose that a string matches the pattern. Then what? What do you do with that information?

Comment: The idea will be to split the string again by ``-->`` and store each time interval separately. But the question is about the regex I came up with, and if it's the most efficient to validate the pattern I presented. I'm not thinking ahead of that (yet).

Comment: I'm far to be an expert in Regex. But you may have used `\d{2}` instead of `\d\d`

Comment: @gervais.b Oh that's good. Can I also use ``\\d{3}`` for ``\\d\\d\\d``?

Comment: @Morgan Yes, of course, you can alos go a little deeper by repeating the _00:_ twice : `(\d{2}:){2}`. And if your goal is to extract both parts, you can use capturing groups : `((?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2},\d{3}) --> ((?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2},\d{3})`  http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRiqgfU0DA/index.html

Comment: Regarding a small optimization, turn "p" into a constant (`private final static Pattern PATTERN_TIMESTAMP = Pattern.compile("...");`).  Compiling each and every call to patternMatch is fine and good if you're planning on using it once, but I'm guessing you're using it to search through log files, am I right?

Comment: yes i concur with @gervais.b: it is probably better in this case to use a quantifier

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using \d, you might want to limit the matcher to valid ranges.

```
\d{2}:([0-5]\d:){2},\d{3}
```

would match either of the timestamps and it would prevent someone from entering

```
11:88:88,888 --> 12:99:99,999
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for any valid time interval, you should consider to allow strings like:

```
0:0:0,0-->12:03:4,344
```

Try this:

```
^\s*\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2},\d{1,3}\s*-->\s*\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2},\d{1,3}\s*$
```

Comment: In this case, the example you provided isn't considered a valid time interval. The string needs to contain double digits for H, M, and S and three digits for milliseconds.